# Cannot access Titanium Mobile Database

Tags: database, titanium, appcelerator

My code below is a simple Titanium mobile application for Android. I implemented database to create a table in it. But the code i wrote doesn't work for me. I created db file in resource folder also. But there is no change in the database. Is my code to connect database correct? Someone please verify my code and answer me the query.

```
var win = Ti.UI.createWindow({
    title:'Window',
    backgroundColor:'black',
    borderColor:'grey'
});

var label1 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Welcome to new Window',
    color:'white',
    font:{fontSize:20},
    top:10
});

var text1 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
   top:50,width:200
});

var text2 = Ti.UI.createTextField({
   top:100,width:200
});

var db = Titanium.Database.open('testdb');

db.execute('INSERT INTO tips (title, tip ) VALUES(?,?)','santhosh','sathya');

db.close();

win.add(label1);

win.add(text1);

win.add(text2);

win.open({fullscreen:false});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have an existing SQLite database file that you want your application to use, then you must install it first.

```
Titanium.Database.install( 'path/to/file.s3db', 'testdb' );
```

However, be aware that once you install it, the file you specify above *is not* the database that will be in use by the app.  Per [this guide](http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Working+with+Local+Data#WorkingwithLocalData-Creatingadatabase):

> On the other hand, `install()` will copy
>   a pre-existing database file from
>   Titanium's `Resources` directory, or one
>   of its descendants, to
>   `applicationDataDirectory/../databases/`
>   and return a reference to the opened
>   database.

Answer (score 0):

your database cannot be in your resources folder, that directory is read only from the application perspective.

please take a look at this documentation

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/td/250+Working+With+Local+Data

https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/examples/database.js

Answer (score 0):

I have also same problem in starting Time. I give you a step by Step answer.

Lets try for sort out your problem:

1. after your create data base in your application resources folder. You firstly clean or project.
2. than u install properally through the code `(Titanium.database.install('.....sqlite','<database>');`
3. than open  : `db=Titanium.database.open(<database>);`
4. than execute : `db.execute(' your Syntax ');`
5. than Close : `db.close();`